# var document.getElementById("title").value; issue

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a form but when it submits, all the fields are blank. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<form><p>
        Remind me about: <input type="text" id="title"><br>
        Where: <input type="text" id="where">
        Notes: <input type="text" id="notes"><br>
        Start Date and Time: <input type="datetime" id="startDate" placeholder="October 13, 1975 11:10:00">
        End Date and Time: <input type="datetime" id="endDate" placeholder="October 13, 1975 11:15:00"><br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="calendarDemoAdd(this.form)"></p>
      </form>
```

and the Javascript:

```
var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("endDate").value);


var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
var where = document.getElementById("where").value;
var notes = document.getElementById("notes").value;

var calSuccess = function(message) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
var calError = function(message) { alert("Error: " + message); };
function calendarDemoAdd() {window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title,
where,notes,startDate,endDate,calSuccess,calError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have failed to give the input elements `name` attributes.

Only controls with names can be successful.

It is possible (although it would fail to follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)) to replace the data collection and encoding functionality of the `<form>` with JavaScript, but there is no sign that the JS you have is doing that.

Comment: Hi Quentin. I added the names as suggested but still get only blank fields. Could there be anything else?
If I do the following it works fine:
var title = "this is a Title";
etc
etc

Comment: If the problem is to do with reading the data into the JavaScript (as opposed to submitting the form as the question says) then you'll need to provide a lot more information about what the JS is doing, how you are triggering it, how you are testing the values, and what the browser's JavaScript error console is reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like name attribute is missing for all the input fields

```
<form><p>
    Remind me about: <input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br>
    Where: <input type="text" name="where" id="where">
    Notes: <input type="text" name="notes" id="notes"><br>
    Start Date and Time: <input type="datetime" name="startDate" id="startDate" placeholder="October 13, 1975 11:10:00">
    End Date and Time: <input type="datetime" name="endDate" id="endDate" placeholder="October 13, 1975 11:15:00"><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="calendarDemoAdd(this.form)"></p>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual fix was

```
function calendarDemoAdd() {
var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
var where = document.getElementById("where").value;
var notes = document.getElementById("notes").value;
  window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title,where,notes,startDate,endDate,calSuccess,calError);
}
```

The reason is that the variables were populated before the function was run.